# How to rotate two UIView's?

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios, ios4, rotation

I created a app with the iOS 4.1 SDK.

In this app I did the following: I add two UIView's as subview to the Window of the Application. One view is a navigationcontrollerview and the other is a view that displays advertisement. The user can then navigate trough the app will the ads are displayed uninterrupted.

Now comes the problem: I wanted to add the option to rotate the device from portrait to landscape and back. The problem is only the first view (in my case the navigationcontrollerview) is rotated without problem. The second view is never rotated. Documentation from Apple confirms that this is the default behavior.

So, how do I get my second view rotated? Do I need to restructure my application? And why is the second view never rotated? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Can you include the link to the documentation you've found for this problem? I thought that everything inside the root view would be rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just adding the second view (the one that doesn't rotate) as a plain UIView? If so, try adding it after containing it within a UIViewController class. I had the same issue in my app not so long ago. instead of [window addSubview:sampleView], I did [window addSubview:[sampleViewController view]]; where sampleViewController subclasses UIViewController.

In general, always use corresponding view controllers and contain views in them and then add subviews to avoid these issues.